# iphone XS, " std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::~basic_string()" Crash

Tags: c++, ios, unreal-engine4

Why does Unreal Engine4 iOS building link libsdtc++ which is obsoleted by Apple iOS few years ago,  rather than libc++  ?

And this problem leads to the Crash, " std::__1::basic_string, std::__1::allocator >::~basic_string()"

And this crash has no workround on iphone X or newer ios devices.

Unreal4 community: https://answers.unrealengine.com/questions/414057/view.html

**Crash Stack：**

```
Incident Identifier: 07780217-40B2-4A87-BDBD-595CC17B4005
CrashReporter Key:   de3c8097b74148a89e279a8fcf404033823d140b
Hardware Model:      iPhone7,1
Identifier:          com.Duang.AgoraThird
Version:             0.42 (1.0)
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Non UI
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           com.Duang.AgoraThird [1410]

OS Version:          iPhone OS 12.2 (16E227)
Baseband Version:    7.55.01
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:  EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY
Triggered by Thread:  34

Application Specific Information:
abort() called

Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7470f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7465a0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb45cb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40bc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   GraphicsServices                0x000000022ed4079c GSEventRunModal + 104
6   UIKitCore                       0x0000000258fb3b68 UIApplicationMain + 212
7   AgoraThird                      0x00000001012e850c 0x100abc000 + 8570124
8   libdyld.dylib                   0x000000022c6068e0 start + 4

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 3 name:  Dispatch queue: com.Metal.CommandQueueDispatch
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7470f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7465a0 mach_msg + 72
2   IOKit                           0x000000022ce77660 io_connect_method + 412
3   IOKit                           0x000000022ce1125c IOConnectCallMethod + 172
4   IOAccelerator                   0x000000022ec88334 IOAccelCommandQueueSubmitCommandBuffers + 160
5   Metal                           0x000000022ecc8dac -[MTLIOAccelCommandQueue submitCommandBuffers:count:] + 648
6   Metal                           0x000000022ecf9db4 -[_MTLCommandQueue _submitAvailableCommandBuffers] + 720
7   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c5f57d4 _dispatch_client_callout + 16
8   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c59a018 _dispatch_continuation_pop$VARIANT$mp + 412
9   libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c5a9fa4 _dispatch_source_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 1308
10  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c59e1ec _dispatch_lane_serial_drain$VARIANT$mp + 284
11  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c59ee3c _dispatch_lane_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 428
12  libdispatch.dylib               0x000000022c5a74a8 _dispatch_workloop_worker_thread + 596
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d5114 _pthread_wqthread + 304
14  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cd4 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cd0 start_wqthread + 0

Thread 5 name:  com.apple.uikit.eventfetch-thread
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7470f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7465a0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb45cb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40bc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x000000022d50dfcc -[NSRunLoop+ 32716 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x000000022d50de5c -[NSRunLoop+ 32348 (NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 96
7   UIKitCore                       0x0000000259099540 -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 136
8   Foundation                      0x000000022d63a6e4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   Metal                           0x000000022ecf5668 -[_MTLCommandBuffer waitUntilCompleted] + 80
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015164bc 0x100abc000 + 10855612
4   AgoraThird                      0x0000000101515894 0x100abc000 + 10852500
5   AgoraThird                      0x0000000101540c08 0x100abc000 + 11029512
6   AgoraThird                      0x000000010151e344 0x100abc000 + 10888004
7   AgoraThird                      0x000000010154be40 0x100abc000 + 11075136
8   AgoraThird                      0x0000000101be4814 0x100abc000 + 17991700
9   AgoraThird                      0x0000000101be4394 0x100abc000 + 17990548
10  AgoraThird                      0x0000000102a57c64 0x100abc000 + 33143908
11  AgoraThird                      0x0000000102a571fc 0x100abc000 + 33141244
12  AgoraThird                      0x0000000102a56ae0 0x100abc000 + 33139424
13  AgoraThird                      0x00000001026ebd28 0x100abc000 + 29556008
14  AgoraThird                      0x00000001012e63dc 0x100abc000 + 8561628
15  AgoraThird                      0x00000001012e1f60 0x100abc000 + 8544096
16  AgoraThird                      0x00000001018764d4 0x100abc000 + 14394580
17  Foundation                      0x000000022d63a6e4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
19  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
20  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 7 name:  AVAudioSession Notify Thread
Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7470f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7465a0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb45cb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40bc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   AVFAudio                        0x00000002329fe378 GenericRunLoopThread::Entry+ 574328 (void*) + 156
6   AVFAudio                        0x0000000232a28c60 CAPThread::Entry+ 748640 (CAPThread*) + 88
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 8 name:  TaskGraphThreadNP 0
Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1d34 0x100abc000 + 11492660
3   AgoraThird                      0x000000010159fb60 0x100abc000 + 11418464
4   AgoraThird                      0x000000010159f928 0x100abc000 + 11417896
5   AgoraThird                      0x000000010159f804 0x100abc000 + 11417604
6   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
7   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  PoolThread 0
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 10 name:  PoolThread 1
Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 11 name:  PoolThread 2
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 12 name:  PoolThread 3
Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 13 name:  PoolThread 4
Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 14 name:  PoolThread 5
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 15 name:  PoolThread 6
Thread 15:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 16:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7470f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7465a0 mach_msg + 72
2   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb45cb4 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 236
3   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40bc4 __CFRunLoopRun + 1360
4   CoreFoundation                  0x000000022cb40354 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436
5   Foundation                      0x000000022d50dfcc -[NSRunLoop+ 32716 (NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 300
6   Foundation                      0x000000022d54949c -[NSRunLoop+ 275612 (NSRunLoop) run] + 88
7   Foundation                      0x000000022d63a6e4 __NSThread__start__ + 984
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 17 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 0
Thread 17:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 18 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 1
Thread 18:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 19 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 2
Thread 19:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 20 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 3
Thread 20:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 21 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 4
Thread 21:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 22 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 5
Thread 22:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 23 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 6
Thread 23:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 24 name:  FImgMediaSchedulerThread 7
Thread 24:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001013e4588 0x100abc000 + 9602440
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 25 name:  FMediaTicker
Thread 25:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x000000010247cc54 0x100abc000 + 27003988
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 26 name:  PoolThread 7
Thread 26:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 27 name:  PoolThread 8
Thread 27:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 28 name:  PoolThread 9
Thread 28:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 29 name:  PoolThread 10
Thread 29:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 30 name:  PoolThread 11
Thread 30:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 31 name:  PoolThread 12
Thread 31:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015b1c94 0x100abc000 + 11492500
3   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015ec6e4 0x100abc000 + 11732708
4   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015cdb2c 0x100abc000 + 11606828
5   AgoraThird                      0x00000001015c1104 0x100abc000 + 11555076
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 32 name:  AURemoteIO::IOThread
Thread 32:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7470f4 mach_msg_trap + 8
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7465a0 mach_msg + 72
2   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000230a50230 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run+ 950832 () + 256
3   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000230a551a0 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry+ 971168 (void*) + 76
4   AudioToolbox                    0x0000000230e2688c CAPThread::Entry+ 4974732 (CAPThread*) + 88
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 33 name:  Trace
Thread 33:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100b9fb4c 0x100abc000 + 932684
3   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100ba2280 0x100abc000 + 942720
4   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100ba1e9c 0x100abc000 + 941724
5   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100ba1ce8 0x100abc000 + 941288
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 34 name:  AgoraServiceThread
Thread 34 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c7520dc __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cb094 pthread_kill$VARIANT$mp + 380
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x000000022c6abea8 abort + 140
3   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000022c7a5780 _malloc_put + 0
4   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000022c7a5938 malloc_report + 60
5   libsystem_malloc.dylib          0x000000022c7985e8 free + 532
6   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000022bd5fc1c std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::~basic_string+ 257052 () + 32
7   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100be5ad4 0x100abc000 + 1219284
8   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100bea490 0x100abc000 + 1238160
9   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100be8498 0x100abc000 + 1229976
10  AgoraThird                      0x0000000100c27c94 0x100abc000 + 1490068
11  AgoraThird                      0x0000000100c27fc4 0x100abc000 + 1490884
12  AgoraThird                      0x0000000100ceb338 0x100abc000 + 2290488
13  AgoraThird                      0x0000000100ced818 0x100abc000 + 2299928
14  AgoraThird                      0x0000000100cd9364 0x100abc000 + 2216804
15  AgoraThird                      0x0000000100be8c70 0x100abc000 + 1231984
16  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
17  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
18  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Thread 35 name:  RtcEngineNotificationThread
Thread 35:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000022c751ee4 __psynch_cvwait + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7cccf8 _pthread_cond_wait$VARIANT$mp + 636
2   libc++.1.dylib                  0x000000022bd29090 std::__1::condition_variable::wait+ 32912 (std::__1::unique_lock<std::__1::mutex>&) + 24
3   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100cf9a00 0x100abc000 + 2349568
4   AgoraThird                      0x0000000100cf9c64 0x100abc000 + 2350180
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d42c0 _pthread_body + 128
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d4220 _pthread_start + 44
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000022c7d7cdc thread_start + 4

Binary Images: 
...
```

Comment: This is missing a lot of context, beyond the fact that some code (which we can't see) is crashing trying to destruct a string. There's a lot of interesting details we don't know, including how/where the string was allocated, its lifetime, when the dtor was called, who owned it, whether any other pointers to it were leaked and wrongly deleted, etc. Some code (particularly a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)) would be extremely helpful.

Comment: Protobuf  is also crashed on  UE 4.  Why does UE 4 not support iOS dynamic library which can fix  this issue too ?